# d3.csv.parseRows and d3.csv output different results

Tags: csv, d3.js

I am working with a data set that requires some clean up before I can visualize it with d3.

I will show a simplified version, I am trying to create the equivilant of a csv file.

Why are the outputs different?

```
// create header for csv
var csv_test = "date, one, two, three\n";

function init() {
    for (i=1;i<25;i++) {
        // create the csv
        temp = "1/"+i+"/14" +"," + i + "," +i*2 + "," + i*3 + "\n";
        csv_test += temp;
    } 
    console.log(csv_test);

    var new_csv = d3.csv.parseRows(csv_test);
    console.log(new_csv);

    d3.csv("test.csv", function(error, data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
}
init();
```

csv_test outputs the following:

```
date, one, two, three
1/1/14,1,2,3
1/2/14,2,4,6
1/3/14,3,6,9
1/4/14,4,8,12
```

now if I use d3.csv.parseRows(csv_test) it returns this:

```
[Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], etc
```

if I copy and paste the original csv_test from the console into a new .csv file and use d3.csv I get a different output in the console:

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, etc]
```

How do i get d3.csv.parseRows to output the same results as loading the data with d3.csv?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear why you would want to do that, but this is one way of achieving that:

```
var new_csv = d3.csv.parseRows(csv_test).slice(1).map(function (d) {
    return { date: d[0], one: d[1], two: d[2], three: d[3] };
})
```

Note that I have removed the header row from the parsed rows before converting them to an object.

Now you can get clever and determine the object to construct by reflectively parsing the first header row and dynamically creating the returned object.

Comment: I don't want to use the file, it's just an example of what the desired output is. I want the data created from the loop to be used with d3.csv.parseRows, matching the output of d3.csv.

Comment: thanks @musically_ut but my goal is not to have the data come from a file. I want to generate it from a loop in a csv format, then use d3 to treat it as if it were actually loaded from a file using d3.csv ...  i was hoping d3.csv.parseRows would accomplish that but as you can see the outputs are different. "[Array[4], Array[4]]" vs "[Object, Object]" thx

Comment: @snake_pliskin Sorry, I had completely misunderstood your intent and the question though I have to admit that your intentions are murkier to me now. Hope the updated answer helps.

Comment: yes, exactly! it's not an ideal situation, but the data is being updated automatically and the file is actually originally an xls, which is very messy. thank you sir.

Answer (score 1):

The reason parseRows returns arrays is because it assumes there is no header row. Therefore, it doesn't require an Object to store the information, so it will just put then entire row into an array.

d3.csv on the other hand (as well as d3.csv.parse()), does assume the first row is the header row. So it requires an object in order to store the column name.

You will likely have to convert the array to an object yourself.